# HashBytes works on sql server 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2000, md5

i have a client that runs a windows application on a sql server 2000 database, and i am trying to run a query that works fine on sql server 2005, with the HashBytes function like this:

```
SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5','some text'), 3, 32) AS MD5
```

but i don't know if this function works on sql server 2000, so i don't want to send to him something that may not work.
So, can you tell me if this is going to work on my client?
If not.. what alternatives i have to save that 'some text' in md5 format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HASHBYTES` was introduced in SQL 2005, for 2000 you would need an *extended stored procedure*, for example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/xp_md5.aspx

Comment: A friend told me about a sha function... this function exists?

Comment: By default that's only available with HASHBYTES on 2k5+